# What happens if my question is closed, and a moderator recommends reposting it to another site?

Tags: discussion

After [How do I tell my dermatologist that I took more Epuris than he prescribed, without offending him?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/17850/14407) was closed, [this moderator](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/how-do-i-tell-my-dermatologist-that-i-took-more-epuris-than-he-prescribed-witho?noredirect=1#comment31123_17850) recommended posting to IPS.

But I'd shudder at seeing [this detailed first-rate answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/17854/14407)  be deleted.

Comment: You probably won't be able to delete the question on your own anyways, since there's an upvoted answer. There's no need to worry about the answer being lost.

Comment: If you do want to try IPS, run it through our [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/1599) first. Questions on how to communicate without offending often end up being closed for 'asking what to say' instead of focusing on 'how to say it', the community can help you with editing this to include the necessary details to make it a good question. For a bit of light reading, there's also [How do I write a good question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1599). Right now, your post isn't likely to be migrated due to the risk it runs of being closed on IPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now... nothing special happens. All that moderator did was post a comment. The question/answer won't be deleted unless people vote to delete it, which seems unlikely considering the circumstances. Even if it was deleted, you (as the question owner) should be able to still see the answer if you have a link to the page.

If the question was migrated (and in this case you would need a moderator to do so), both the question and its answer would be migrated to the new site, causing them both (answers immediately, question after 30 days) to be deleted on the original site.